# Can't pop up a datepicker using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I want to add a datepicker in a website which is using jQuery, appery.io framework. Could anyone please suggest a link or tutorial to do this?Trying to pop up a datepicker in a website where right now it's only showing the current date in an input box like this:

```
<input type="text" name="cal" id="cal_id".....>
```

the javascript library have been used are jquery-1.8.2.js, jquery-1.8.2.min.js, jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js etc.

I tried JQuery UI datepicker from http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/. Added the javascript files: code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css, code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js, code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js. Added script as this:

```
<script>
            $(function () {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            });

        </script>
```

in the input box made changes like this:

```
<input type="text" name="cal" id="datepicker"...>
```

it's not working or popping up the datepicker in the website. I am a new programmer in javascript & appery.io, I guess I am doing something very silly or missing something very basic. please help.

[I also tried some other datepickers from http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/timestamp.shtml, http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php, http://www.kean.edu/~cpd/calendar/zapatec/zpcal/doc/wizard.html..nothing seemed to work for me.]

When I try to refresh the page, it shows 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' and 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'activePageClass' of undefined '.

Update: Now datepicker pops up only when I refresh the page! So when I navigate to this Calendar page and click on the input box, it doesn't work or doesn't pop up the datepicker. But if I refresh the page in browser, then it works!! Please help!

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: No error! It just not doing anything!

Comment: your script is working for me

Comment: It's working now. It was clashing because the datepicker() function was in another js file and also I had rearrange the css files order. Thanks.

Comment: Ohh! it's working only when I refresh the page! So when I navigate to this Calendar page, it doesn't work or doesn't pop up the datepicker. But if I refresh the page in browser, then it works!! Any idea? @ Alexandru Severin, @j08691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is working for me. Did you add jquery-ui.css ?

Add this to your site:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js'></script>                       
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dGmLy/)

Tested with:
jQuery-2.0.2, jQuery-UI-1.10.3

**EDIT:**
Based on your comments, I deduced that your calendar is added dynamically after the script is called. Your jquery function only affects elements found when the page loads, for dynamically added elements you need to take a look at Jquery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) functions.

Try replacing your script with:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', "#datepicker", function (e){
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong going on. The calendar doesn't pop up or nothing happens. When I try to refresh the page, it shows 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' and 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'activePageClass' of undefined '. Can it be because I am attaching both jquery-2.0.2.js/jquery-1.10.2.js and jquery-1.8.2.js?

Comment: @MSI - "Can it be because I am attaching both jquery-2.0.2.js/jquery-1.10.2.js and jquery-1.8.2.js?" Possibly. You shouldn't include multiple version of jQuery in the same page.

Comment: Ohh! it's working only when I refresh the page! So when I navigate to this Calendar page, it doesn't work or doesn't pop up the datepicker. But if I refresh the page in browser, then it works!! Any idea? @ Alexandru Severin, @j08691

Comment: How are you navigating to the page? is the datepicker added dynamically?

Comment: When I navigate from another page, I do it through an onclick function like this: "Appery.navigateTo('CalendarPage', {
                        reverse: false
                    });"

Comment: @MSI it seems to me that your page filter doesn't change the whole page, just its content, so the calendar is added after your script is called. I updated my answear

Comment: Unfortunately still it's doing the same thing after I made changes as you suggested. Not pop up the datepicker on click when I navigate to the page from some other page, but it works fine after I refresh the page.